# Polymer paper-input does not update nested property

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x

Does paper-input support nested properties? For example,

```
<paper-input label="FIRST NAME" value="{{client.name}}"></paper-input> //client object is updated
<paper-input label="LAST NAME" value="{{client.address.street}}"></paper-input> //client object is not updated
```

`client.name` is updated when user enters text into paper-input but `client.address.street` is not updated when user enters text into paper-input. i.e. client object only contains `{name: 'xxx}` and not `{name: 'xxx', address: {street: 'abc'}}`

Is there any documentation out there that mentions the above limitations or did I do something wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Polymer` doesn't provide a way to bind directly to an array item. You have to use data binding helper elements from `polymer` (like [template repeaters](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat)) for nested scopes.

Use one of the following ways to interact with arrays in a data binding:

- The [dom-repeat](https://www.polymer-project.org/2.0/docs/devguide/templates#dom-repeat) helper element lets you create a instance of a template for each item in an array. Inside a `dom-repeat` instance, you can bind to the properties of the array item.

  ```
  <dom-repeat items="{{client}}" as="client">
    <template>
      <paper-input label="FIRST NAME" value="{{client.name}}"></paper-input>
      <paper-input label="LAST NAME" value="{{client.address.street}}"></paper-input>
    </template>
  </dom-repeat>
  ```
- The [iron-list](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/iron-list) displays a virtual, 'infinite' list. The template inside the iron-list element represents the DOM to create for each list item.

  ```
  <iron-list items="{{client}}" as="client">
    <template>
        <paper-input label="FIRST NAME" value="{{client.name}}"></paper-input>    
        <paper-input label="LAST NAME" value="{{client.address.street}}"></paper-input>
    </template>
  </iron-list>
  ```

If you initialize a property i.e. an object or array value using a function, it will ensure that each element gets its own copy of the value, rather than having an object or array shared across all instances of the element. You don't have to user helper element as above:

```
client: {
    type: Object,
    value: function() {
           return {
            "name": "",
            "address": {
              "street": ""
           }
          };
        }
}
```

[Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/VegnYGK1ojYBMqiDFK3G?p=preview)

Comment: thanks. But {{client.address.street}} does not get updated when a user inputs value into paper-input. Im trying to understand why that happens.

Comment: I didnt get the chance to try the attached demo provided. The plunker is not rendering... seems the same with jsbin for polymer elements. Problem with polygit?

Comment: Thanks. I finally got to test out the plunker you created. It does work. So if I only have one set of non-repeating inputs, wouldn't it be an overkill to wrap it in an iron-list or dom-repeat?

Comment: Answer updated. Also, you can check the updated demo as well.

Comment: Thanks for the plunker. I realised how to reproduce my issue. If the objects are uninitialised (i.e an empty object), the nested properties do not get updated. Please see the following plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/Lf25iNImSHT0IT6wEJix?p=preview

Comment: Yeah you have to initialise if you have nested property like I was doing in the demo.

Comment: Do you know why there is such a limitation? Would you mind adding the initialisation requirement as part of your answer and I'll accept it? Thanks for your help. Really appreciate it.

Comment: I had updated my answer earlier. Did you check the last part?

Comment: yes i did. But the issue was really caused by the need to initialise nested data else changes wouldn't be picked up by paper-input. Would you mind being more explicit on that for the answer? I still don't know why we need to initialise data though and if you could shed some light on that, that would be perfect. Cheers.

Comment: It is not `paper-input`, `polymer` needs the array or object to be initialise nested data.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I'll accept it as the answer but to me, the real answer was provided by you in the comments :) Thanks a lot for helping me figure it out.